# Unable to use colors to paint in GNU Image Manipulation Program except black color

Tags: colors, gimp

I am using the **"GNU Image Manipulation Program"** to edit some images. I am selecting "Red", "Green" or whatever color, but when I start "**Painting"** or  "**Bucket fill tool**" it's not working. I only see a black color, not the one, I selected.

This is the screenshot. I have selected #e90202 but I am getting only Black:

[image: This is the screenshot. I have selected #e90202 but I am getting only Black]
 Please help me out. I need to make a logo for my blog.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, please save it once and open the picture by another app. I think the background colour should be white when you open this. Thus it might be a failure of the Ubuntu theme, colour scheme doesn't draw properly. You can choose default colour scheme then report this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Too bad you didn't include the title bar in the screenshot, but it is likely telling that the image is color-indexed. In these images, the colors are actually indices to a color map, and Gimp will not alter the colormap, it will instead replace your color by the closest color. Change you image to full-RGB (`Image>Mode>RGB`) and you should be able to use any color n it.